# State of GeoServer SQL Server Extension

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, spatial-database

Does anyone know what the current state of the SQL Server extension for GeoServer is?

When it came out in 2008, there were a lot of complaints of poor performance, as the comments in this blog show: http://blog.geoserver.org/2008/11/10/146/.

Has any further work been done on it since then?

Comment: I think this question would be more suited to the GIS Chat Room or being addressed directly to the developers of that extension.

Comment: I think the original question, while certainly responded to with an opinion, was specifically soliciting facts: has work been done on the extension since 2008.  I marked your response as the answer because of the first word, which was the Boolean response I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has extension (rather than community module) status, so there is at least some support. However there are better database options (those in core distribution are likely better supported than extensions, which in turn are better supported than community modules, broadly speaking). I'd generally suggest PostGIS first.

Whether SQL Server and the geoserver (mostly GeoTools) module suit your needs depends on your situation (which you haven't really described) and to some extent, opinion. I can only suggest trying it with representative workloads.

I'd still suggest PostGIS except that this would really be an opinion and we try to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, things have moved on since 2008. The SQL Server datastore does support indexes now, you can even use the better jtds-sqlserver driver which helps speed things up.

I know of large commercial sites that make use of the plugin in production environments. That said it will always be slower than a "proper" spatial DB like PostGIS because of design decisions taken by MicroSoft so I would avoid it like the plague.